# Show an additional (/) button in the input field?

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Could you please tell me how I could have an additional (/) button in the input field ? As shown here in this image:

https://core.telegram.org/file/811140659/1/RRJyulbtLBY/ea6163411c7eb4f4dc

I have written a bot using this library: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot.

And found out that:

"Show an additional (/) button in the input field in all chats with bots. Tapping it types a '/' and shows the list of commands."

in this page: https://core.telegram.org/bots#commands.

Unfortunately my bot does not have that, using the Telegram app on my iphone.

I also have tried to provide the list of commands using Botfather, but still no yield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set the commands with Botfather, it should work. Alternatively, you can set the commands programmatically with the [`setMyCommands`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setmycommands) method - in `python-telegram-bot`, that's [`Bot.set_my_commands`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.set_my_commands).

Comment: I actually did set the commands wit Botfather as you said and it still not appear, even after close and open the Telegram app back. One thing though, there is a item call "Menu" appear at the very left of the input, and will list all the commend when it is pressed. I still not yet have the privilege to add image for demonstrate.

Comment: The "Menu" thingy is the new version of the slash. they just didn't update https://core.telegram.org/bots#commands yet …

Comment: I see, but it is quite inconvenient in my opinion. Some of my command need a user input, not ready to run right a way. Additional slash is nicer. Thank you so much for your answer @CallMeStag ! I will mark it as solve.

Comment: In the previous design, the commands where also immediately sent, that hasn't change

Comment: Yes, however,  if I remember correctly, after the list of comment is shown, if I do not choose a command to sent and continue to type, I still can type a command with input. I hope I do not confuse you with my description. I mean, with the slash, it also acts as a shortcut of the slash key.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's true. You could ask TG to restore that behavior, either through support or maybe through bugs.telegram.org.