# How to create a three dashes menu on a Telegram bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

How could I create a three-dashes menus on a Telegram bot, similarly to what they do to the Jobs bot? It should be similar to this:

[image] [image]

How do we call this kind of menu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show an additional (/) button in the input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68524047/show-an-additional-button-in-the-input-field)

Comment: It is not really the same thing.

Comment: Tell botFather what commands are available, then the button will appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **java** case with [this library](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots).

**if the commands already was created**, so simply in the class that extends TelegramLongPollingBot:

```
 this.execute(new GetMyCommands());
```

**In other case:**

1. Create new List BotCommand

   List<> commandsList = new ArrayList();
2. Adding BotCommand to the list with name and description

   commandsList.add(new BotCommand("commandName", "description"));
3. Create a new SetMyCommands whit the botCommandList and executed

   this.execute(new SetMyCommands(commands));

more information about: https://telegram.org/blog/animated-backgrounds#bot-menu

Comment: Since OP didn't specify a programming language, he's probably looking for a generic solution. A Java only solution, based on same random library won't help OP.

Comment: ok, understand. Sorry, I am very new and I can't ask him in a comment. Maybe the last link help.  https://telegram.org/blog/animated-backgrounds#bot-menu 
Thank you for the feedback 0stone0

Comment: Actually this answers my question. Even if the answer was in Java, at least I can navigate my way to the implementation in Python, which is the one I wanna use. Thanks @Federremu!

Answer (score 10):

You can add your commands which will be displayed on the menu using the Bot father commands.

I followed the below steps:

- Open BotFather send command /setcommand
- BotFather will ask for the bot you want to set the command
- Provide the command name along with the description in "command - description" format

Now open your bot and the command you send will be displayed on the Menu.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but it does not work. maybe need something else?

Comment: In which step are you getting failure?

Comment: I removed my bot and created again. After it everything works :)

Comment: That's great..!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a solution using `python-telegram-bot`, here is a simple code reference:

---

```
from telegram import BotCommand
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, Application, CommandHandler

config = dotenv_values(".env")

command_info = [
    BotCommand("hello", "Say hello to the bot"),
]
command_handlers = [
    CommandHandler("hello", hello),
]


async def post_init(application: Application) -> None:
    bot = application.bot
    await bot.set_my_commands(commands=command_info)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    log("Starting bot...")
    app = (
        ApplicationBuilder()
        .token(config["BOT_TOKEN"])
        .post_init(post_init)
        .build()
    )
    app.add_handlers(command_handlers)
    log("Bot started!")
    app.run_polling()
```

References:

- [ApplicationBuilder `post_init` in docs](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.applicationbuilder.html#telegram.ext.ApplicationBuilder.post_init)
- [GitHub example](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/rules-bot/blob/master/rules_bot.py)